# CSS image pushing grid item down

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I've been trying to put an image inside a grid but its causing me problems.
Right now, my biggest issue is that is pushing another grid item down.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(20, 1fr) / repeat(20, 1fr);
}

.main-bar {
  grid-row: 1/16;
  grid-column: 4/21;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(20, 1fr) / repeat(20, 1fr);
}

.main-info {
  grid-column: 1/21;
  grid-row: 1/21;
  background: #333;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(20, 1fr) / repeat(20, 1fr);
}

.header-title {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2/8;
  background: #000;
}

.business {
  grid-column: 17;
}

.side-bar {
  background: #fff;
  grid-row: 1/21;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
  border-right: 1px solid #0F6B99;
}

.side-bar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -24px;
}

.home-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0F6B99;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.buy-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #59B3B3;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.sell-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #8FCCB8;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

.rent-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #B8E6B8;
  grid-row: 6/7;
}

.article1 {
  background: #e6174b;
  grid-row: 16/21;
  grid-column: 4/11;
}

.article2 {
  background: #8FCCB8;
  grid-row: 16/21;
  grid-column: 11/18;
}

.article3 {
  background: #B8E6B8;
  grid-row: 16/21;
  grid-column: 18/21;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-bar">
    <div class="main-info">
      <img class="business" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/businessman/businessman_PNG6564.png" alt="">
      <div class="header-title">High Quality Realstate Asistance</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <!--<img src="img/logo.png" alt="">-->
    <div class="home-button">
      Home
    </div>
    <div class="buy-button">
      Buy
    </div>
    <div class="sell-button">
      Sell
    </div>
    <div class="rent-button">
      Rent
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article1">
  </div>
  <div class="article2">
  </div>
  <div class="article3">
  </div>
</div>
```

The image in question has a class as `business` and the item is pushing down has a class as `header-title`. Header-title should be inside main-info, but when 'business' appears, it pushes header-title down!
!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your image with the *business* class is overflowing its own grid and the grid of its container.

In order to resolve this add the property overflow: hidden to both the .main-info class and the .business class.

These classes also need the "display: grid" property so the browser can process the grid-column and grid-row property accordingly for those two classes.

Once those additions are made you can tweak the grid-row and grid-column for the the .business class and the .header-title classes accordingly to find your desired positions.

Full CSS and HTML Below:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(20, 1fr) / repeat(20, 1fr);
}

.main-bar {
  grid-row: 1/16;
  grid-column: 4/21;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(20, 1fr) / repeat(20, 1fr);
}

.main-info {
  grid-column: 1/21;
  grid-row: 1/21;
  background: #333;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(20, 1fr) / repeat(20, 1fr);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-title {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2/8;
  background: #000;
  display: grid;
}

.business {
  grid-column: 17;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
}

.side-bar {
  background: #fff;
  grid-row: 1/21;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
  border-right: 1px solid #0F6B99;
}

.side-bar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -24px;
}

.home-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0F6B99;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.buy-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #59B3B3;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.sell-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #8FCCB8;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

.rent-button {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #B8E6B8;
  grid-row: 6/7;
}

.article1 {
  background: #e6174b;
  grid-row: 16/21;
  grid-column: 4/11;
}

.article2 {
  background: #8FCCB8;
  grid-row: 16/21;
  grid-column: 11/18;
}

.article3 {
  background: #B8E6B8;
  grid-row: 16/21;
  grid-column: 18/21;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-bar">
    <div class="main-info">
      <img class="business" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/businessman/businessman_PNG6564.png" alt="">
      <div class="header-title">High Quality Realstate Asistance</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <!--<img src="img/logo.png" alt="">-->
    <div class="home-button">
      Home
    </div>
    <div class="buy-button">
      Buy
    </div>
    <div class="sell-button">
      Sell
    </div>
    <div class="rent-button">
      Rent
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article1">
  </div>
  <div class="article2">
  </div>
  <div class="article3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the 'header-title' apear, but if the image is placed in the code, I can't modify its grid-row and grid-column position properly. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Got it, I modified the original post with a comprehensive answer that allows you to modify the grid-row and grid-columns.